# If the intersection of a sequence of open sets is a null set, can the intersection of the closures have positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Hi everyone: Suppose $(V_{n})$ is a sequence of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ for $N\geq2$. If $\bigcap_{n}V_{n}$ has Lebesgue measure zero, can we conclude that the intersection of the closures $\bigcap_{n}\overline{V_{n}}$  is also a null set?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you're asking this for $N\ge2,$ I guess you know how to get a counterexample in $\mathbb R^1.$ Well, if $(V_n)$ is your counterexample in $\mathbb R^1,$ won't $(V_n\times\mathbb R^{N-1})$ do the same trick in $\mathbb R^N$?

Answer (score 2):

By outer regularity, for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $S \supseteq \mathbb{Q}^N$ such that $\lambda^N(S) < \epsilon$. Taking $\epsilon = 1,\frac 1 2, \frac 1 3, \frac 1 4, \dots$, there exists a sequence $(S_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is a null set, but their closure....

Explicit construction of $S_n$(Skip this part if you are satisfied with outer regularity): Let $\{q_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}^n$. Then

$$ S_n = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \operatorname{Cube}\left(q_j; \frac{1}{\sqrt[N]{n} 2^{j/N}} \right)
$$
where $\operatorname{Cube}(x,r) = ]-\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{2}[^N + x$ is an open box of side length $r$ centred at $x$. Then
$$\lambda^N （S_n） = \lambda^N \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \operatorname{Cube}\left(q_j; \frac{1}{\sqrt[N]{n} 2^{j/N}}\right) \right)
\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[N]{n} 2^{j/N}}\right)^N = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n 2^j} = \frac{1}{n}
$$